# How to retrigger getStaticProps after an update?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js

On a personal project related to an online shopping website I have a list of the products page, I'm trying that after I delete a product to refetch the products. I'm using Next.JS and Firebase as a database.
The first time when the page is loaded I'm getting the products with getStaticProps

```
export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
    const items = Array.from(await getItems({shouldShuffle: false}));
    // more code + return items
}
```

How can I recall the items var after deleting a product to refetch items?

Answer (score 0):

You can investigate using [On-demand Revalidation (Beta)](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration#on-demand-revalidation-beta), which allows you to manually purge the Next.js cache for a specific page.

This only works for `v12.1.0` or more. If you're in a previous version, you will not be able to purge/bust the cache unless you either redeploy or set a [`revalidate` property](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-props#revalidate) that specifies the seconds after which an automatic page re-generation will occur.

Comment: I made t hat revalidate.js file, but how can I call it after I just deleted an item?

Comment: const deleteItemHandler = async () => {
        setShowNotification(false);
        await deleteDoc(doc(db, 'clothes', id)).catch((error) => console.log(error));
        closeShowDeleteModal();
        await fetch('/api/revalidate?secret=' + secretKey);
        await setShowNotification(true);
    }
Is this good?

Comment: @AWXMEDIA You need to call the `/api/revalidate` endpoint from outside the Next.js app whenever an item is deleted. How that is done depends entirely on how the item gets currently deleted in Firebase database - I'd recommend a read through https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events.